# Git converting CRLF to LF in images

Tags: git, git-add

Everytime i add a new image to my project, Git convert CRLF to LF. It would be okay if the files came from windows, but it does not, I'm on Debian !
The files i'm getting from "pull" on my remote server are then corrupted =/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `.gitattributes` file, where you put :

`*.png binary`

But it is quite strange that it isn't the case by default .

Maybe you use some other uncommon image format ?

Comment: Windows font maybe !

Comment: Perfect. I renamed the corrupted files directory so git detect the modifications. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

My problem was the `.gitattribute` file contained the line `* text eol=lf` which converted **all** files to text, including images. When changing the line to `* text=auto eol=lf`, git automatically detects whether a file is a binary and doesn't touch its line endings.

Comment: I mistakenly assumed that the default value would be auto, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

In my case,there's a .gitattribute file with content `* text=auto eol=lf`. after add edi9999's answer(*.png binary), perfect.